# Keras after test prediction values steadily decreases and goes down

Tags: machine-learning, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

**Issue:**

I'm trying to predict the future stock price of Google using the LSTM model in Keras. I'm able to train the model successfully and the test prediction also goes well, but the after test/future prediction is bad. It forms a steadily decreasing curve which is not an actual future data.

**Some Explanation**

I'm training the model with two inputs and expecting a single output from it.

```
# Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
sc = MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (0, 1))
training_set_scaled = sc.fit_transform(training_set)

# Creating a data structure with 60 timesteps and 1 output
X_train = []
y_train = []
for i in range(2, 999):
    X_train.append(training_set_scaled[i-2:i, 0])
    y_train.append(training_set_scaled[i, 0])
X_train, y_train = np.array(X_train), np.array(y_train)

# Reshaping
X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 1))


# Part 2 - Building the RNN

# Importing the Keras libraries and packages
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dropout

# Initialising the RNN
regressor = Sequential()

# Adding the first LSTM layer and some Dropout regularisation
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], 1)))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

# Adding a second LSTM layer and some Dropout regularisation
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

# Adding a third LSTM layer and some Dropout regularisation
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

# Adding a fourth LSTM layer and some Dropout regularisation
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

# Adding the output layer
regressor.add(Dense(units = 1))

# Compiling the RNN
regressor.compile(optimizer = 'rmsprop', loss = 'mean_squared_error')

# Fitting the RNN to the Training set
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 500, batch_size = 50)
```

**Testing the predicted model**

```
dataset_test = pd.read_csv('/media/vinothubuntu/Ubuntu Storage/Downloads/Test - Test.csv')
real_stock_price = dataset_test.iloc[:, 2:3].values

# Getting the predicted stock price of 2017
dataset_total = pd.concat((dataset_train['data'], dataset_test['data']), axis = 0)
inputs = dataset_total[len(dataset_total) - len(dataset_test) -0:].values
inputs = inputs.reshape(-1,1)
inputs = sc.transform(inputs)
X_test = []
test_var = []
for i in range(0, 28):
    X_test.append(inputs[i:i+2, 0])
    test_var.append(inputs[i, 0])

X_test_pred = np.array(X_test)
X_test_pred = np.reshape(X_test_pred, (X_test_pred.shape[0], X_test_pred.shape[1], 1))
predicted_stock_price = regressor.predict(X_test_pred)
```

This part goes very well, the  test prediction give a perfect result.

**After test/future prediction:**

```
for x in range(0,30):
    X_test_length = X_test[len(X_test)-1] # get the last array of X_test list   
    future=[]
    Prev_4 = X_test_length[1:2] # get the last four value of the X_test_length
    Last_pred = predicted_stock_price.flat[-1] # get the last value from prediction
    merger = np.append(Prev_4,Last_pred) 
    X_test.append(merger) #append the new array to X_test
    future.append(merger) #append the new array to future array 
    one_time_pred=np.array(future)
    one_time_pred = np.reshape(one_time_pred, (one_time_pred.shape[0], one_time_pred.shape[1], 1))   
    future_prediction = regressor.predict(one_time_pred) #predict future - gives one new prediction
    predicted_stock_price = np.append(predicted_stock_price, future_prediction, axis=0) #put the new predicction on predicted_stock_price array
```

Here comes the actual problem, I'm getting the last value from the test prediction and predicting a single output and creating a loop on the new precited value. [Please suggest me a better way, if you feel this is a bad idea]

**My output:**

[image: Click here to view the output]

**Expected Result:** Actual future data, which is definitely not a decreasing curve.

Comment: I see more issues in your code, but to be able to help you, you must provide some sample or dummy data.

Comment: @Geeocode Sure, you can access the code and sample files in the link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ptHdyUglmvBVYZ_wY8ctvGB9VcivoCFk Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you wanted here: `get the last four value of the X_test_length`. Why `four`?
Note: In python `[1:2]` is the same like `[1]`. Furthermore `X_test[len(X_test)-1]` is the same as `X_test[-1]`. Actually I don't really care, how do you write them in your code, I just wanted to know, that your intention was what how you wrote.

Comment: I am intending to give you answer to your base issue, but I wanted to know, if there are accidental indexing errors in your code.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. please ignore the commented text, as i added that earlier while experimenting and later decided to change the number of test values to 2.

Comment: I'm actually trying to get the future data from the model, as it requires an initial data to predict a value, I'm taking the final value from the prediction test.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204318/discussion-between-tom007-and-geeocode).